# Export node Metrics to Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, fluentd, fluent-bit

I am trying to evaluate which logging tool to use. Does fluentd offer something similar to fluentbits [node-exporter?](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/inputs/node-exporter-metrics)
(The same question applies to kube-state-metrics)

Is what i am searching somehow related with [the metrics docs?](https://docs.fluentd.org/metrics)

Do i have to readjust the metrics myself(With fluend ofc) and send them to prometheus with the push model, or should i use prometheus pull method?